# How to correctly validate number ranges in HTML Input? (Angular 2)

Tags: regex, html, forms, angular

In my Angular 2 application I have a component with a **input** field which is supposed to accept a range of numbers.

More specifically, 2 cases:

- range 0[0]-23 (hours)
- range O[0]-59 (minutes)

I am using

```
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]"> <!-- 0-9 -->
    <input type="text" pattern="\d|1\d|2[0-3]"> <!--  0-23 -->
    <input type="text" pattern="\d\d"> <!--  [0-99] -->
</form>
```

The issue is that I can basically input anything (**as if validation was ignored**), including text.
I don't think it's an issue related to **Angular 2** since standard validation works, e.g.

```
 <input type="number">
```

allows to input only **numbers** (but **any** number which is not what I want)

I also tried with **min**=0 and **max**=23 (or 59) attributes with type **number** but that doesn't work either.

Comment: it's not. I think the issue is some missing attribute somewhere but I have no clue where

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="9"> <!-- 0-9 -->
    <input type="number" min="0" max="23"> <!--  0-23 -->
    <input type="number" min="0" max="99"> <!--  [0-99] -->
</form>
```

Comment: thanks @Gunter. I tried that. maybe it works but there is no output at all (I need to validate the form in real time, I'm not sure whether on submit it'd return an error). I finally solved the "Angular way" as explained in my answer. if you can explain how it's supposed to work, I'll be happy to accept the answer!

Comment: I'll check with a plunker but not today anymore

Comment: did you have the chance to try?

Comment: I was away a few days. It's not working. `min` and `max` requires `type="number"` but because of https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2961 it still doesn't work currently. See also https://plnkr.co/edit/CT9aoN7xu9OJgaCY0pid?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I hope it will work soon (when the issue is fixed)

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, 
I solved by using **Angular 2's FormBuilder** as in:

**ts**

```
   ...

   constructor(...
               private formBuilder: FormBuilder);


   timeForm: ControlGroup;

    ngOnInit(){
        let regexPatterns = {
           // this can be improved
           hours: "[0-2]?[0-9]?",
           minutes: "[0-5]?[0-9]?"
        };

        this.timeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           hour: ['', Validators.pattern(regexPatterns.hours)],
           minute: ['', Validators.pattern(regexPatterns.minutes)]
       });
```

**html**

```
       <form [ngFormModel]="timeForm">
            <!-- additional validation (HTML 5) for 'required' -->
            <input type="text" required ngControl="hour">
            <input type="text" required ngControl="minute">
       </form>
```